# Responsive grid in just 1 row

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been using bootstrap a while but can't get my head around this.

So, I have 1 row with 4 cols in it, the responsive part this time is that as I keep making size of screen smaller, I want to drop the elements that don't fit. That means that I start showing 4 images one next to the other, later on if screen is smaller I just want to show first 3, and in the end probably only 1.

Is is possible to do this with CSS or am I going to need some Javascript.

I hope I explained well enought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To completely hide or show based of the display size, use :
`visible-xs-*`, `visible-sm-*`, `visible-md-*`, `visible-lg-*`, `hidden-xs`, `hidden-sm`, `hidden-md`, `hidden-lg`

`*` corresponds to `block`, `inline` and `inline-block`, depending on what you want.

```
<div class="row">
    <div>
        1
    </div>
    <div class="hide-xs show-sm-block">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="hide-xs show-sm-block">
        3
    </div>
    <div class="hide-sm show-md-block">
        4
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I know how bootstrap works, What is gonna happen is div 4 is going to break into next line once we reach col-cm.

I want div number 4 to disapear instead of going to next line

Answer (score 0):

If you want div 4 to disappear for a small screen you can simply hide it for small screens.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    1
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    2
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    3
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 hidden-sm">
    4
</div>
```